# Mercurial - How to restrict read access of user A to project B?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

According to the [documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories):

```
<Location /hg>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Mercurial repositories"
    AuthUserFile /home/user/hg/hgusers
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

This would allow read/push of all projects within /var/hg/repos for authenticated users.

So far so good. But how do I restrict User A to read/push to Project B?

Comment: Did you try more-specific location and AuthGroupFile?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AclExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AclExtension) to deny push rights, I don't know for read ones.

Put something like :

```
[hooks]
  pretxnchangegroup.acl = python:hgext.acl.hook
[acl]
  sources = serve
[acl.deny.branches] 
  * = A # deny access for user A to all branches
```

In the `.hgrc` of the B repository.

If you want to deny read access too, you can also configure a particular `<location>` for this specific repository in Apache which doesn't contain the unwanted user.